# How do you send an array to a modal for use in Laravel 5.5 blade with in_array for checkboxes to set the checked attribute?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade, fullcalendar-3

I am trying to pass an array to a modal after I get a response from an ajax call on the eventClick() function in fullcalendar v3

// in my blade javascript section

This is getting good data but I need to send the tagcodes to the modal and an array like this..

```
$tagCodes
```

which should be an array like this..

```
'AM','FLEX'
```

A. I don't know how to make it a usable array.

B. I need to send it to the front-end as a variable called $tagCodes which is an array.

```js
eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
    let id = event.id;
    let tag_codes = event.tag_codes;
    console.log(tag_codes.split(" ").join(",").replace(/,\s*$/, ""));

    ( which is giving me this AM,FLEX )

    $.ajax({
        url: '/agenda/' + id,
        type: 'GET',
        data: {},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#calendarModal input[name=id]').val(data.calendar.id);
            $("#calendarModal .tagCodes").html(tag_codes.split(" ").join(",").replace(/,\s*$/, ""));
            $('#calendarModal').modal();
        }
    });
}
```

// in my modal section

```
<div class="col-12">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 tagCodes"></div>
        @foreach($tags as $tag)
        <div class="col-3 text-center">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"
                id="tag-{{ $tag->id }}" name="tags[]" value="{{ $tag->id }}"
                @if( in_array($tag->code, [THIS IS WHERE IM TRYING TO SEND THE ARRAY]) ) checked @endif
                > {{ $tag->code }}
            </label>
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: blade template works on server, JavaScript runs on the client, you can't change server side variable from client. what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: i want to pass this: 

```$("#calendarModal .tagCodes").html(tag_codes.split(" ").join(",").replace(/,\s*$/, ""));```

to the front using jquery i guess so i can assign the check boxes with the ones that should be checked.

I am getting the data from the server via ajax. when the modal is licked I need to check the checkboxes that are in it with the data im getting from the server.

Comment: you can't change blade template with JavaScript, it is just used to generate html you need.

Comment: try using jquery to enable the checkboxes like `$('#tag-2').prop('checked', true);` not in php code.

Comment: I have seen this before. get ajax data and then check the checkboxes in front end based on the data from the server. i just can't remember. the data is a string separated by a space. thats why im splitting and rejoining with a comma. 

in the blade im doing a foreach

Comment: is it the data is like `1 3 4 5` where theses are the indexes you need to check?

Comment: no they are strings example would be: 'AM FLEX PM'

```@if( in_array($tag->code, ['AM','FLEX','PM']) ) checked @endif```

Comment: ```@foreach($tags as $tag)
        <div class="col-3 text-center">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"
                id="tag-{{ $tag->id }}" name="tags[]" value="{{ $tag->id }}"
                @if( in_array($tag->code, [THIS IS WHERE IM TRYING TO SEND THE ARRAY]) ) checked @endif
                > {{ $tag->code }}
            </label>
        </div>
        @endforeach```

Comment: can jQuery send an array of data as a variable?

Comment: posted an answer, check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
<input type="checkbox"
                id="tag-{{ $tag->id }}" name="tags[]" value="{{ $tag->id }}"
                @if( in_array($tag->code, [THIS IS WHERE IM TRYING TO SEND THE ARRAY]) ) checked @endif
                >
```

to

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="tag-{{ $tag->code }}" name="tags[]" value="{{ $tag->id }}">
```

then in JavaScript do this.

```
var codes = tag_codes.split(" ");
for(var i=0;i<codes.length;i++)
$('#tag-'+codes[i]).prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: This is working perfectly now. Thank you so much. As this is my first post I can't thank you enough. You have save me hours of frustration